After Installing Ubuntu 24.04, Graphic Card Fan is Running Loudly
Previously my PC was running Windows 10 with no issue.
Then i decided to change to Ubuntu. During installation and until after installation, the GPU fan was spinning ludly.
What is the cause?
FYI: GPU is GF108 [GeForce GT 730]

Welcome to AskUbuntu. There is an insufficient amount of information here to do anything but guess wildly. As such, it would be good to start with the basics: (1) by “loudly” do you mean the fan is spinning at 100% and not slowing down? (2) Have you installed the driver for the video card? (3) Have you tried changing the idle fan speed through nvidia-settings?


How do i check if the fan is spinning at 100%? 2) Yes 3) No, how do I do that?

